# Refactoring my httpclient into a restsharp in my .Net Maui app getting Could not resolve type with token with a simple attempt to connect

Tags: maui, restsharp

I am trying to integrate RestSharp into my project, but am getting this error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 010000d5
> from typeref (expected class 'RestSharp.ConfigureRestClient' in
> assembly 'RestSharp, Version=110.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75')'

I've tried removing and reinstalling RestSharp, NewtonsoftJSON, Community.MVVM, and the MAUI Community Toolkit.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  Can anybody point me in the right direction for getting this fixed?  My web and stackoverflow searches aren't leading to anything helpful so far.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a post on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2399) with the solution.  Seems I just needed to delete the **bin** and **obj** folders from my project, then restart VS.